# Why is fopen throwing a warning when response is HTTP 204 (Empty Content)?

Tags: php, asp.net-mvc

I am using PHP fopen() to make a GET request to an ASP.NET MVC endpoint. When the request is succesful, there is an empty response and an HTTP 204 status code.

However, fopen is throwing a warning so I'm trying to figure out the best way to resolve this.

```
$handle = fopen("http://myservice.com/test.php?foo=bar", "r");
```

Warning is:

```
Warning: fopen(http://myservice.com/test.php?foo=bar) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 204 No Content in E:\web\test.php on line 18
```

I'm confused as to why fopen is even throwing a warning.  What is the best way to handle this? Should I:

1. Prefix fopen call with "@" to suppress warnings?
2. Change the webservice to return some content like "OK" so the status will be a HTTP 200 OK?
3. ... something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it should not. All 20x status codes should be treated as ok. But it might depend on your version of PHP. Since PHP5.3 it checks for the `response_code >= 200 and < 400` and only complains otherwise.

But PHP 5.2 for example: http://svn.php.net/repository/php/php-src/branches/PHP_5_2/ext/standard/http_fopen_wrapper.c contains this tidbid:

```
        switch(response_code) {
            case 200:
            case 206: /* partial content */
            case 302:
            case 303:
            case 301:
                reqok = 1;
                break;
```

This excludes your `204` status code and would explain why the following code triggers a warning. (At least there's no need to file a bug report, as it apparently has been already.)

In this case I'm not sure if it suits your use case, should be used with care, but `@` would indeed suppress the warning.

Comment: Thanks for the details on the solution as well as the cause. My server is indeed running PHP 5.2.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use `fopen()`, this is what I dug up.

```
$context = stream_context_create(
    array('http' => array('ignore_errors' => 1))
    );
$handle = fopen("url...", "r", false, $context);
```

Using these leads:

- http://nadeausoftware.com/articles/2007/07/php_tip_how_get_web_page_using_fopen_wrappers
- https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create.php
- https://www.php.net/manual/en/context.http.php

You may also want to consider something such as `curl`.

Answer (score 0):

If all you're doing is checking the response, you may want to check out: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php

Edit: I just looked at some of my code that gets an HTTP status and it looks like I've been using the suppression operation. This code has been in production for years and there have been no problems (aside from relying on the fopen URL wrappers):

```
$fp = @fopen($url, 'rb');
if (isset($http_response_header[0])) $http_status = $http_response_header[0];
if ($fp) fclose($fp);
```